# vue js disable input if value hasn't changed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, binding, vuejs2, disabled-input

I have an input with an initial value:

```
<input type="text" v-model="name" ref="input" />
<button type="submit" :disabled="$refs.input.defaultValue == $refs.input.value">Submit</button>
```

However the `disabled` binding gives an error: `Cannot read property defaultValue of undefined`.
Best way to do this without spamming vm.data too much?

Comment: "this gives an error" ... and the error is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error:

> Cannot read property defaultValue of undefined

Is because the [`ref`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) is not available so soon:

> An important note about the ref registration timing: because the refs
> themselves are created as a result of the render function, you cannot
> access them on the initial render - they don’t exist yet! `$refs` is
> also non-reactive, therefore you should not attempt to use it in
> templates for data-binding.

And when you add it to the `button`'s template, it tries to use it too soon.

The workaround would be to add a simple conditional:

```
<button type="submit" :disabled="!$refs.input || $refs.input.defaultValue == $refs.input.value">Submit</button>
```

But don't be happy just yet.

## The `defaultValue` won't have the value you think

When using `v-model`, `defaultValue` will actually always be empty string (`""`) because Vue initially renders the `<input>` with an empty value.

To use a variable in the disabled button like you want, my suggestion is: use a `mouted()` logic to "save" the initial value and, in the button template, compare to it instead of `defaultValue`.

Demo below.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    name: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$refs.input.dataset.defVal = this.$refs.input.value;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ name }}</p>
  <input type="text" v-model="name" ref="input" />
  <button type="submit" :disabled="!$refs.input || $refs.input.dataset.defVal == $refs.input.value">Submit</button>
</div>
```

## Alternative: Going Vue all the way

Of course, if it's a possibilty, you should take advantage of Vue's data-driven reactive nature, as tackling with the DOM is always tricky.

The solution would be to just create another variable and populate it on `mounted()`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    name: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    defaultName: null
  },
  mounted() {
    this.defaultName = this.name;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ name }}</p>
  <input type="text" v-model="name"/>
  <button type="submit" :disabled="name == defaultName">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Or, if you can set both `name` and `defaultName` to the same initial value, the `mounted()` logic above wouldn't even be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

My solution would probably be more verbose than using a disabled flag. But I would use:
@click.prevent="submit"

Then make a submit method to handle the check, return false if input has not changed.